# Need Blocking UI for disabled/outdated Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm checking and resolving Google Play Services Availability like

```
public static boolean resolvePlayServices(@NonNull final Activity context) {
        final int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(context, resultCode, GMS_REQUEST_CODE);
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to Resolve GMS Error: " + resultCode);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Moreover I've added version info in Menifest file

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Play Services on my testing device is disabled and outdated, but the resultCode I'm getting is `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` and clicking on the update button is doing nothing except pausing and resuming the activity (as play services are disabled).
How can I get the resultCode `SERVICE_DISABLED` and dialog for opening the play services settings page.

Moreover, the dialog returned by `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog` is cancelled if I press the back button or touch outside the dialog and the application continues to run.

How can I get the functionality like this-
[In case Play Services are not updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7iq5.png)

Or like this (Gmail App)-
[If play services is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVzKJ.png)

Which blocks the application from continuing if user doesn't enable/update play services.

Comment: Assuming you have Google Play services, are you then connecting to it via a `GoogleApiClient`? Or some other way?

Comment: I'm checking Google Plat Services before using https://developers.google.com/vision/ which doesn't need `GoogleApiClient` to be connected.